# Retrieving Data through 3 tables. Laravel 9

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, api, eloquent

I have 3 tables (brands - categories - products).
Each product belongs to One brand and belongs to many categories.
There's a brand page which will display the products of this brand and the categories of products of the brand so I want to get the categories of the brand using laravel 9 and send the data to an API.

**The Structure**

```
products
  id
  title
  brand_id
  price
  etc...
```

```
categories
  id
  title
  description
  parent_id
```

```
product_categories
  product_id
  category_id
```

```
brands
  id
  title
  logo
  description
```

**Models**
*Product.php*

```
    public function brand()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Brand::class, 'id', 'brand_id');
    }

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'product_categories');
    }
```

*Category.php*

```
public function parent()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Category::class, 'id', 'parent_id');
    }


    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
    }
```

*ProductCategory.php*

```
public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
    
    public function Products(){
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'id', 'product_id');
    }
```

*Brand.php*

```
public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
```

I'm expecting to get the categories of the brand.

Comment: Well... at least you posted relevant code... so now... you already tried something. What did you try? Which joins did you try? Which selects? Show that relevant part of your code as well

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want to use the result and where you want to structure it you can simply do this

```
$brand = Brand::with(['products.category'])->first($id);
```

This will load a given brand, with all it's products, and then for all those products load their given categories. It will use just 3 quieres to get all the data and the give you the full object like so:

```
$category = $brand->products[0]->category[0];
```

Products will be a collection (that could be empty) and so will category

If you want to slim this down to just a list of unique categories you can do the following.

```
$list = $brand->pluck('products.category.name', 'products.category.id');
```